# How to add google fonts to React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-fonts

I have a project created with `npx react-native init myProject` to which I want to add external Google sources, in this case `Lobster-regular`.

First, install via terminal `"@ expo-google-fonts/lato" and "@expo-google-fonts/oswald"` following a tutorial.
Perform the imports in the App.js file:

```
import {
  useFonts as useOswald,
  Oswald_400 Regular,
} from '@ expo-google-fonts / oswald'

import {
  useFonts as useLato,
  Lato_400Regular,
} from '@ expo-google-fonts / lato'
```

And create these constants:

```
const [oswaldLoaded] = useOswald ({
  Oswald_400 Regular,
})

const [latoLoaded] = useLato ({
  Lato_400Regular,
})

if (! oswaldLoaded ||! latoLoaded) {
  return null;
}
```

I have a file in which with my personal styles in which I call the fonts, colors, font sizes, etc:

```
export const fonts = {
  body: "Oswald_400Regular",
  heading: "Lobster-Regular",
  monospace: "Oswald_400Regular",
}
```

All this has not worked.

**ExceptionsManager.js: 180 Unrecognized font family 'Lobster-Regular'**

Finally, override all the above code, and I have manually downloaded and added the Lobster-Regular fonts, in the assets folder at the root of the project.
It is also added in:

- projectApp / assets
- android / app / src / main / assets / fonts
- In iOS it is also in projectApp / Resources

I have created a file called react-native.config.js where I added the following and ran react-native link:
( [How to add custom fonts to react-native v0.61.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498030/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-react-native-v0-61-x))

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    Android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

However, when I call sources from a file this only works on Android

```
font-family: $ {(props) => props.theme.fonts.heading}
```

**ExceptionsManager.js: 180 Unrecognized font family 'Lobster-Regular'**

What should I do for the fonts that I want to work on iOS?

Comment: It seems like you didn't actually install Lobster-Regular. You just installed oswald and lato.

Comment: "Finally, override all the above code, and I have manually downloaded and added the Lobster-Regular fonts". That sentence bothers me. Are you saying that the code you show isn't the code which is actually used? And why would you manually download the font when you should be able to install it in the same way that you installed oswald and lato?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68570172/13170636) should solve the problem. Let me know.

Comment: Gentleman, I say this, to show all the alternatives that I have used and can offer ideas @EmilKarlsson

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by downloading the correct sources and performing `react-native link`

Comment: https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

Comment: Thanks @NooruddinLakhani  , this is the way I chose to correct the error, and I can now add as many fonts as necessary. If you wish, create an answer and show details and I will accept it. If you don't, I will.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if React Native Version ≥ 0.60

Create File [react-native.config.js](https://miro.medium.com/max/4800/1*-84uwCzEGBkzns13Zo0r-g.png) and add the following code

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ["./assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
};
```

if React Native Version < 0.60

You need to tell react native where our custom fonts are located. Adding the following lines in your package.json

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

Path can vary. if you have “src” folder and you want to put assets in “src” folder then path will be “.src/assets/fonts/”

Run in terminal

```
$ npx react-native link
```

For details implementation, read the [article](https://mehrankhandev.medium.com/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4)